# Is APUE wrong about linux threads description?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

In Figure 11.2 APUE 2nd, there is a code demoing usage for threads API, as below:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_t ntid;

void printids(const char *s)
{
        pid_t pid;
        pthread_t tid;

        pid = getpid();
        tid = pthread_self();
        printf("%s pid %u tid %u (0x%x)\n", s,
                (unsigned int)pid, (unsigned int)tid, (unsigned int)(tid));
}

void *thr_fn(void *arg)
{
        printids("new thread: ");

        return (void*)0;
}

int main(void)
{
        int err;

        err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, thr_fn, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
                return -1;

        printids("main thread: ");
        sleep(1);
        return 0;
}
```

and the book says the output is like this,

```
$./a.out
new thread: pid 6628 ...
main thread: pid 6626 ...
```

Pid is different ! This is because "Linux use the clone() to implement threads, same as fork(), so the system consider the threads as separate processes who share resources".

But When I tested, I found the result is different from the APUE result, which is

```
$ ./a.out 
main thread:  pid 13301 tid 3078153920 (0xb778e6c0)
new thread:  pid 13301 tid 3078151024 (0xb778db70)
```

the pid is the same ! so is APUE outdated ? But linux do use clone to implement threads, and in linux kernel, they are viewed as different processes. How come the process ID is the same ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a high chance that your edition APUE might be outdated in the sense that it refers to LinuxThreads instead of NPTL.

Here's the relevant section from the clone(2) manpage that sheds light on this issue:

"*Thread groups were a feature added in Linux 2.4 to support the POSIX threads notion of a set of threads that share a single PID.   Internally,  this shared PID is the so-called thread group identifier (TGID) for the thread group.  Since Linux 2.4, calls to getpid(2) return the TGID of the caller.*

*The threads within a group can be distinguished by their (system-wide) unique thread IDs (TID). A  new  thread's  TID  is available as the function result returned to the caller of clone(), and a thread can obtain its own TID using gettid(2).*"